# Retrieving username and password from Mongodb using php with angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, mongodb

I have created a simple login page using mongodb , angular js and php. when the user login from the database by retrieving username and password from the database, it goes to the admin page. But the login from database is not responding as unable to fetch data from db

index.php: 
This is the homepage of the website.

```
  <?php
   include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

   ?> 
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LoginIN</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
   <link href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="styles/signin.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
     </head>
    <body>
     <?php
     if(isset($error) and count($error) > 0){
     ?>
     <div class="errorContainer"> <ul>
     <?php foreach($error as $err) echo '<li>'.$err.'</li>'; ?>         
     </ul></div>
      <?php 
     }

      if(!empty($success)){
    echo '<p class="text-success">'.$success.'</p>';
     }
    ?>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <header id="top">
     <center><h1>Leave Reporting System</h1></center>
    <div class="container">
   <div ng-app ='angularPost' ng-controller='loginCtrl'>
  <form class="form-signin" role="form"  action ="" method="post">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

  <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="username" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required>
     <br>
     <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
     <input type="checkbox" value="remember" name ="remember">Remember me
     <br>
     </label>
     </div>
     <input name="submit"button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  ng-click=login() type="submit" value=" Sign in">
            <span>{{responseMessage}}</span>
           <br>
     <a href="">Forgot your password?</a> 
     </form>      
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

login.php

```
  <?php
  $succss = "";
   if(isset($_POST['submitForm'] )){


   $usr_email = $_POST['username'];
   $usr_password = $_POST['password'];

   $error = array();
   if(empty($usr_email) or      !filter_var($usr_email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)){
    $error[] = "Empty or invalid email address";
    }
    if(empty($usr_password)){
    $error[] = "Enter your password";   
      }
    if(count($error) == 0){
    $con = new MongoClient();
    if($con){
        // Select Database
        $db = $con->lrs;
        // Select Collection
        $Login = $db->Login;
        $qry = array("username" => $usr_email,"password" => md5($usr_password));
        $result = $Login->findOne($qry);
        if($result){
            $success = "You are successully loggedIn";
            // Rest of code up to you....   
        }           
    } else {
        die("Mongo DB not installed");
    }   
}
  }   
 ?>
```

app.js

```
     var app = angular.module('angularPost',[]);
     app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http)
     {
     $scope.login = function() {
      var request = $http({
        method : "post",
        url  : "login.php",

        data : {
            email : $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        },
    });
    request.success(function(data)
    {
        if(data == "1"){
            $scope.responseMessage = "Successfully Logged in";
        }
        else{
            $scope.responseMessage= "Username or Password is invalid"
        }
    });
}
 });
```

Comment: In your `login.php` the `$_POST['username']` should be `$_POST['email']`. Angular is not posting the inputs of your forms. You're sending the data `email:, password:`